# Where are Charizardite X and Y found in ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Where can I find Charizardite X and Y in Pokémon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire? I can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 2):

Charizardite X can be found in the Fiery Path, while Charizardite Y can be found in the Scorched Slab, both only after completing the main story.